# Why can't iPhone 11 on iOS 13.0 upgrade to 13.2.2?

Tags: software-update, ios

A friend got a brand new iPhone 11 just over three weeks ago. It's running iOS 13.0 (17A577), so presumably it hasn't ever had a software update.

When my friend tries to update iOS to the current version (13.2.2), the "Verifying update..." dialog appears for a while, then the

A dialog then appears, saying:

> **Unable to Install Update**
>
> An error occurred installing iOS 13.2.2
>
> <kbd>Retry</kbd>
>
> <kbd>Remind me later</kbd>

Retrying ends up with the same result.

iOS 13 has various fairly serious bugs, including super-slow tap responsiveness (several seconds passing before taps on the screen register).

Is there any way to get past this error and get my friend's iOS updated?

Comment: Did your friend tried Reset Network Settings? (Settings app → General → Reset).

Comment: Also my favorite iPhone troubleshooting step: back up the phone locally (use a password on the backup!) completely erase the phone (Settings > General > reset > erase all content and settings) and then restore the phone. That often fixes a number of strange problems with iPhones.

Comment: If over-the-air updating fails on the device, try updating using a computer over USB (see linked duplicate).

Comment: @grg So I found a solution, but it wasn't the one in the linked duplicate (put the iPhone into recovery mode and plug it into a Mac). It was much easier: specifically, deleting the downloaded update from the iPhone's storage in settings, and then running the update again. I'd like to add that as an answer. Should I do it on the linked question, or here?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when unable to update on the device itself due to an error, I use [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) on macOS to install the update.

When Apple Configurator 2 is installed, the process is pretty simple:

1. Open Apple Configurator 2.
2. Plug your iPhone in via USB.
3. Unlock your iPhone. You may need to trust the computer if this is the first time you've connected to it.
4. Your iPhone will now show up in Apple Configurator 2.
5. Right-click your device and select Update...
6. Your computer will now check your iPhone to see if there are any app updates and iOS updates.
7. If there is a new version of iOS available, follow the prompts to install.

If this fails, there could be an issue with the update itself or your iPhone, which may warrant resetting the device.